# Removing CSS as part of custom page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, frontend, custom-theme

I have a custom page layout defined as **lf_cms** in `layouts.xml` file, and am trying to remove the css file as defined in `default_head_blocks.xml` and load a new CSS file, except the CSS changes are not loading.

*What do I need to do to get changes to the CSS files to load on the page?*

I know that the page layout is loading correctly because it's showing up in the admin section under the Design tab on a CMS page. In addition, if I make a syntax error, I get an exception when viewing the page.

*I have also recompiled static assets, cleared caches, and removed var/view_preprocessed files*.

[image: Design section of the CMS page]

> [custom_theme]/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="lf_cms">
        <label translate="true">lf_cms Custom</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

> [custom_theme]/Magento_Theme/page_layout/lf_cms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="1column"/>
    <head>
        <remove src="css/standardStyles.css" />
        <css src="css/customStyles.css" />
    </head>
</layout>
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command, hope this will help.
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work :(